# Jquery code not executed, although loaded

Tags: jquery, flask

I have a flask application which renders a html template which includes jquery code:

```
<script type=text/javascript src="{{ url_for('static', filename='jquery- 
 3.3.1.min.js') }}">
 console.log("hi yah")
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({url: "http://localhost/check", success: function(result){
      $("#div1").html(result);
    }});
  });
</script>
```

However, no matter how I include the jquery in the html, the code is not executed. But when I check the google chrome network tab, I can see, that jquery is loaded.

This one works:

```
<script>
console.log("Hello World")
</script>
```

If I run this code:

```
<script>
console.log("hi yah")
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.ajax({url: "http://localhost/check", success: function(result){
    $("#div1").html(result);
  }});
 });
</script>
```

I get this error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
>       at (index):37

Comment: The error means that jQuery has not been loaded. You've obviously added a `script` reference to it, so I would assume the path is incorrect.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Right, but when I use the first code snippet, nothing happens, not even the console.log("Hello World") is executed.

Comment: That's the opposite of what your question states..?

Answer (score 0):

Try separating your `<script>` tags. Have one `<script>` to fetch the jQuery code, and another for your own JavaScript code like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ url_for('static', filename='jquery-3.3.1.min.js') }}"></script>
<script>  
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({url: "http://localhost/check", success: function(result){
      $("#div1").html(result);
    }});
  });
</script>
```

If that doesn't work, then your file path to fetch the jQuery file is invalid, in which case you can just do this:
`<script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>`

Also, make sure you put quotes around your script type: `type="text/javascript"`

Comment: still doesn't work, although jquery is loaded, I verified in the google chrome network console.

Comment: By "doesn't work", does that mean you're getting errors in the console, or the HTML element isn't getting updated?